# Why can't I install django

Tags: python, django

whenever I go to the command prompt and type`pip install Django==2.0.3` I receive this in red text.

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\commands\install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\req\req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\site-packages\pip\utils\__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\python36-32\lib\os.py", line 220, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'c:\\program files (x86)\\python36-32\\Lib\\site-packages\\pytz'
```

It also tells me that my `pip` installer is out of date, but whenever I try to update it I just receive the same error message.

Comment: Try to launch `cmd` in elevated mode (=admin permissions)

Answer (score 4):

You have a PermissionError on your installation. If Linux user, usually use "sudo" to fix this problem.
And as I see, you use Windows to install Django. So if you are Windows user, you must use "runas".
So, the best way to install Django on your Windows is :

```
runas pip install Django==2.0.3
```

Just try it. Hope that can solve your problem...

Answer (score 1):

Try `pip3 install django==2.0.3`.
You are installing package for Python 3.x , so I guess that could be an issue

Answer (score 0):

By default, common users have listing, reading and executing permissions in Program Files folders and other operations will be blocked by User Access Control(UAC). It is better to install python in your user directory or other partitions rather than system partition.
To solve your problem quickly, you can use "run as administrator" to start cmd, then run pip command again.

Answer (score 0):

As it seems you're on Windows, try to open command-line as Administrator (Easiest way: Searching on Cortana, right click and open as administrator).